# scipy.optimize.brute function: How to pass a specific set of testing?

Tags: python, scipy, range, brute-force

I'm using scipy.optimize.brute to get the minimum value of a function.
I have 4 parameters and its permutation will be huge if I have 10 samples each parameter (10*10*10*10 = 10^4 permutations).   I want to bring it down to < 100 permutations.
Thus, I only want the to test some specific values.

Here is my program I have now:

def f1(x, *params):
     a,b,c  = params
     return x[0]+x[1]+x[2]+x[3]

```
  rranges =  [ slice(0, 1, 0.1),              #10 values
           slice(0, 1, 0.1),           #10 values
           slice(0, 100, 10),         #10 values
           slice(0, 100, 10) ]       #10 values

params = (1,2,3)
bruteforce = spo.brute(f1, rranges, args=params, full_output=True, finish=None)
```

How do I modify rranges so that I only test these set of value I want such as:

```
 rranges =  (0, 0.2, 0.9, 1.0)
            (0.3, 0.4, 0.7, 0.9)
            (10, 15, 90, 95)
            (25, 30, 75, 80)
```

I read the scipy document (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.brute.html)

It said  "Each component of the ranges tuple can be either a slice object or a two-tuple giving a range of values, such as (0, 5). If the component is a slice object, brute uses it directly."

Do you have any advice on how to test only a certain values of the range?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You can't i'm afraid. This function is based on [numpy.mgrid](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mgrid.html#numpy.mgrid), which is a grid with a constant stepsize. The same, constant stepsizes might apply to slice objects (in high-performance tasks this assumption is important).

Comment: That is very helpful., I will have to find another way to tackle this performance issue then. Thanks @sascha

Comment: I never needed brute and i don't think it offers much more than an own custom implementation in most cases, where evaluation is dominating the cost of selecting test-params. So where are you having performance-issues then? Did you measure the time of the complete process vs. function-evals? If it's kind of equal, you can just implement your own method easily using itertools for example.